# Running an app using process.start returns different value than running it manually

Tags: c#, .net, process.start

I'm running a tool that samples the HW PCI for a specific value (I didn't write it).

When I run it from the command prompt, it returns one exit code (the correct one) but when I run it from another application using `Process.Start`, it returns another exit code.

Is there a difference between running an application directly or via `Process.Start`?
Do you know of a simple workaround for this issue?

Comment: Without any real details, who knows? What tool? Do you have source? Does it have docs? Does it describe exit codes? Is the environment the same? Etc, etc, etc.

Comment: *how are you calling `Process.Start`?*

Comment: the tool is company internal.

Comment: @RoiShidlovsky: Then ask the authors or maintainers why that happens. Closing as 'too localized' (sorry).

Comment: the tool is company internal. i do have the source code and its return codes. this tool reads from the PCI and returns '0' if one value is found and '1' if another is found.

Comment: @Roi there are plenty of people here, willing to help. But none of them can work magic. If you were to share *how you are calling `Process.Start`* and the way you run the tool directly from the command line, that might make it possible for someone to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same result from `Process.Start()`, you have to execute your application on
the same working directory as your command line.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Hassan's answer (which solved my similar issue), the exit code returned from Process.Start() is affected by the location of the executable, in particular which directory it is located in. Here's the code I used:

```
    string yourExe = "C\\Program Files\\Your Directory\\YourExe.exe";
    string currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string yourExeDir = "C\\Program Files\\Your Directory";

    try
    {
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(yourExeDir);
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundExeption dnfe)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The specified directory does not exist. " + dnfe.Message);
    }

    if (!File.Exists(yourExe))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Can't find yourExe");
    }
    else
    {
        Process.Start(yourExe);
    }

    try
    {
        //Set the current directory.
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(currentDir);
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dnfe)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The specified directory does not exist. " + dnfe.Message);
    }
```

This switches the current working directory to the directory where the .exe is located, runs it, and then switches back to whatever your previous working directory was.